# Wordpress - upload files and rename with custom user meta

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

when my users upload a file, I need to rename it using a specific **user_meta** value. So, using `wp_handle_upload` I've set a callback function for `$upload_overrides` like this:

```
$upload_overrides   = array( 'test_form' => false, 'unique_filename_callback' => 'change_document_name' );
```

and my callback function is

```
function change_document_name($dir, $name, $ext){
    global $current_user;
    $doc_type = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'document_type', true);
    return $doc_type . '_mydoc' . $ext;
}
```

Now as you can see, we are talking about users documents so I need to rename them according to the document type they've uploaded. For example, if they've uploaded a "**passport**" and selected the document type (of course), I should get the `user_meta` 'document_type', use it as prefix and place it in front of the filename uploaded, outputting something like

- passport_mydoc.pdf

Of course my function doesn't work and I don't understand why it doesn't take the global $current_user or at least if there is some other method to accomplish this.

Many thanks.

**EDIT**

To explain it better, my fault, the function `change_document_name()` does rename the file like so:

- _mydoc.ext (e.g _mydoc.pdf)

This means that the function is correctly called and runs, except for the first part ignoring `$doc_type` variable. For this reason I suppose that the **$current_user** it's not working. My complete code to upload the file is the following:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['docfile'])):
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            $upload_overrides   = array( 'test_form' => false, 'unique_filename_callback' => 'change_document_name' );

            add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_user_folder'); //A documents custom folder
            $uploaded_file      = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['docfile'], $upload_overrides);
            remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_user_folder' );

            $doc_file_loc       = $uploaded_file['file'];
            $doc_file_title     = $_FILES['docfile']['name'];
            $doc_file_arr       = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['docfile']['name']));
            $doc_file_type      = $doc_file_arr['type'];
            $doc_file_att   = array(
                'post_mime_type'    => $doc_file_type,
                'post_title'        => addslashes($doc_file_title),
                'post_content'      => '',
                'post_status'       => 'inherit',
                'post_parent'       =>  0,
                'post_author'       => $uid
            );
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            $doc_file_id = wp_insert_attachment( $doc_file_att, $doc_file_loc, 0 );
            $doc_file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $doc_file_id );
            update_user_meta($uid,'document_file', $doc_file_url);
        endif;
```

The hook `'unique_filename_callback'` is used according to the codex here  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_filename/

Comment: `$upload_overrides` is just a variable with your array of values in it. Show the code where you are actually using it to see how it is registered. Also, is the callback function getting called and not renaming the document? Or is it not getting called at all? Need to expand on 'doesn't work'. Which part isn't working.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley Thank you very much for your comment. My fault! I edited my question and if there is anything more let's talk! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the global isn't returning the user. It should be. But try `get_current_user_id()` and see if it works:

```
function change_document_name( $dir, $name, $ext ){
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        error_log( "User not logged in." );

        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

     // Uncomment to see if there is any value
     // var_dump( $user_id );

    $doc_type = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'document_type', true );

     // Uncomment to see if there is any value
     // var_dump( $doc_type );

    if ( ! $doc_type ) {
        error_log( "There is no doc type set for the current user with id $user_id" );

        return;
    }

    return $doc_type . '_mydoc' . $ext;
}
```

I have added some var_dumps in there you can use to see what values are being returned, or you can debug if you have xdebug set up. But this should give you what you need. You can also remove the error logging if you don't want to log those errors. They are there so you can check the site logs and see what is in them.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I really appreciate your answer. I'm going to test it and mark your answer. Thanks again.